# iOS Caller ID Retrieve

Tags: iphone, objective-c, function, jailbreak

I'm trying to get the caller number (for jailbroken devices) with this code:
extern CFTypeRef CTCallCopyName(void*, CTCall* call);

NSLog(@"%@", CTCallCopyName(NULL, (CTCall*)call));

I receive the error:
  "CTCallCopyName(void*, CTCall*)", referenced from:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6

I have Core Telephony linked with my project.
Maybe my prototype is wrong... i don't know. Any ideas?
Xcode 3, sdk 4

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling this API in a .mm file, you have to declare it like extern **"C"** void foo(void); As far as I know, on iOS 5 ~ 7, you should use CTCallCopyAddress instead, the prototype is:

```
extern "C" CFStringRef CTCallCopyAddress(CFAllocatorRef, CTCallRef);
```

Notice that the second arg is a **CTCallRef** rather than a **CTCall**, which means you can't send it CTCall class methods (although some of them work). Besides linking CoreTelephony.framework, you can also load this symbol dynamically, as shown below:

```
static CFStringRef (*CTCallCopyAddress)(CFAllocatorRef, CTCallRef);

void Foo(CTCallRef call)
{
    void *libHandle = dlopen("/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony", RTLD_LAZY);
    CTCallCopyAddress = (CFStringRef (*)(CFAllocatorRef, CTCallRef))dlsym(libHandle, "CTCallCopyAddress");
    NSString *address = (NSString *)CTCallCopyAddress(kCFAllocatorDefault, call);
    NSLog(@"The caller's address is %@", address);
    [address release];
    dlclose(libHandle);
}
```

BTW, I can't get CTCallCopyName to work in SpringBoard on iOS 5, haven't figured it out or tried on other systems yet. Hope this information helps!

EDIT: Just give it another try on iOS 5, CTCallGetID is the right function to get the caller ID in the addressbook, whose prototype is ABRecordID CTCallGetID(CTCallRef). iOS 6 and 7 are possibly the same.

Comment: I also got `CTCallCopyAddress` to work but `CTCallCopyName` returns nil... I'm on iOS8 non jailbroken, did you have any better luck with this?