# How to get caller details in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios5

Hi am developing a app in which i want to send message automatically to the user who has messaged me or called me. is there any api for getting caller identification? i found [code](http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/iphone-tutorial-how-to-send-in-app-sms/) to send message to particular contact. but i don't know how to get caller id. i got similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365683/ios-caller-id-retrieve) but it is for jailbreak mobile.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this by using Apple approved APIs. You can't send a text message without the user hitting the "send" button either, as this is not approved by Apple.