# Retrieve caller id in IOS 8.3

Tags: ios, iphone, telephony

according to [iOS Caller ID Retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365683/ios-caller-id-retrieve), I have it done to retrieve caller info like that:

```
    NSDictionary *info = (__bridge NSDictionary *)userInfo;
    CTCall *call = (CTCall *)[info objectForKey:@"kCTCall"];
    NSString *caller = CTCallCopyAddress(NULL, call);
```

but after IOS 8.3, there is no address returned from the CTCall. 
before IOS 8.3, I get the CTCall instance like that:

```
{
    kCTCall = "<CTCall 0x17eb85e0 [0x38cb0700]>{status = 4, type = 0x1, subtype = 0x1, uuid = 0x17e89d90 [C5B34D1D-74B8-490A-8252-C9435A418290], address = 0x17e7f9f0, externalID = -1, start = 2.22507e-308, session start = 4.58346e+08, end = 2.22507e-308}";
kCTCallStatus = 4;
}
```

IOS 8.3 I get the instance like this:

```
{
     kCTCall = "<CTCall 0x16d85970 [0x3560c8b0]>{status = 4, type = 0x1, subtype = 0x1, uuid = 0x16d88f90 [F60C14DC-5288-41C1-A96F-C06F08E7757E], address = 0x0, externalID = -1, start = 2.22507e-308, session start = 4.58317e+08, end = 2.22507e-308}";
kCTCallStatus = 4;
}
```

The address of CTCALL is 0. Is there any suggestion? thanks a lot.

Comment: hi , did you get any solution, beacasue i have same issue.